# How do perform time-based audio with Pygame?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, python-3.3

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so here goes:

Edit: I have edited this a few times, just fixing typing mistakes and updating the code. Even after adding various changes to the code, the issue still remains the exact same.
Also, pygame.mixer.music.fadeout() is not what I'm looking for. This code will also be for when I want to lower music volume to perhaps 50% on, say, pausing the game or entering a talk scene.

With Pygame, I am trying to perform music volume manipulation based on how much time has passed. I already have some decent code created, but it's not performing how I thought it intuitively should. Also, I should note that I am using the component-based EBS system I ripped from PySDL2. Here is the link to the EBS module: https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2/src/02a4bc4f79d9440fe98e372e0ffaadacaefaa5c6/sdl2/ext/ebs.py?at=default

This is my initial block of code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Setup import paths for module.
pkg_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
parent_dir, pkg_name = os.path.split(pkg_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(parent_dir, "Game"))

import Game
from Porting.sdl2.ext import ebs

pygame.display.quit()
print("Counting down...")
for n in range(5):
    print(str(n + 1))
    pygame.time.delay(1000)
appworld = ebs.World()
audio_system = Game.audio.AudioSystem(44100, -16, 2, 4096)
appworld.add_system(audio_system)
test1 = Game.sprites.AudioSprite(appworld)
test2 = Game.sprites.AudioSprite(appworld)
test1.audio = Game.audio.Audio(database["BGMusic0"], True)
test2.audio = Game.audio.Audio(database["BGMusic1"], True)
game_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
volume_change_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
loop = True
time_passed = 0
while loop:
    game_clock.tick(60)
    appworld.process()
    time_passed += volume_change_clock.tick(60)
    if time_passed > (10 * 1000):
        print(time_passed)
        if not audio_system.music_volume_changed:
            audio_system.set_music_volume(0, True)
```

My next block of code:

```
import pygame
from Porting.sdl2.ext import ebs
class AudioSystem(ebs.System):
    def __init__(self, frequency, bit_size, channels, buffer):
        super(AudioSystem, self).__init__()
        self.componenttypes = Audio,
        pygame.mixer.init(frequency, bit_size, channels, buffer)
        pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(200)
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.bit_size = bit_size
        self.channels = channels
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.music_volume_change_clock = None
        self.music_volume_changed = False
        self.music_volume_current = 0
        self.music_volume_new = 0
        self.music_fade = False
        self.music_change_speed = 0
        self.time_passed_total = 0
        self.time_passed_remainder = 0

    def process(self, world, componentsets):
        for audio in componentsets:
            if audio.is_music:
                music = pygame.mixer.music
                if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                    music.load(audio.file)
                    music.play()
                if self.music_volume_changed:
                    self.music_volume_current = music.get_volume() * 100
                    if self.music_volume_current != self.music_volume_new and self.music_fade:
                        time_passed = self.music_volume_change_clock.tick(60)
                        self.time_passed_total += time_passed
                        self.time_passed_total += self.time_passed_remainder
                        self.time_passed_remainder = 0
                        if self.time_passed_total > self.music_change_speed:
                            self.time_passed_remainder = self.time_passed_total % self.music_change_speed
                            volume_change_amount = int(self.time_passed_total / self.music_change_speed)
                            self.time_passed_total = 0
                            if self.music_volume_current > self.music_volume_new:
                                self.music_volume_current -= volume_change_amount
                                music.set_volume(self.music_volume_current / 100)
                            elif self.music_current_volume < self.music_volume_new:
                                self.music_volume_current += volume_change_amount
                                music.set_volume(self.music_volume_current / 100)
                    elif self.music_volume_current != self.music_volume_new:
                        music.set_volume(self.music_volume_current / 100)
                    else:
                        self.music_volume_changed = False
                        self.music_fade = False
            else:
                if not audio.channel:
                    audio.channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
                    audio.channel.play()

    def set_music_volume(self, percent, fade = False, change_speed = 50):
        self.music_volume_changed = True
        self.music_volume_new = percent
        self.music_fade = fade
        self.music_change_speed = change_speed
        self.music_volume_change_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Audio(object):
    def __init__(self, file, is_music = False):
        self.is_music = is_music
        if self.is_music:
            self.file = file
        else:
            self.channel = None
            self.file = pygame.mixer.Sound(file)
```

My testing has shown that manipulating the parameter of Clock.tick() in my Game.audio module in various ways influences how quickly the audio playing falls from 100 to 0. Leaving it blank causes it to stop almost instantaneously. At 60, it falls to 0 in around 2 seconds, which baffles me. At 30, in 1 second. At 5, it falls slowly, with the volume never seeming to reach 0. I want to completely desynchronize my audio volume manipulation completely from my game's frame-rate, but I am unsure of how I would accomplish that. I want to avoid threading and multiprocessing if possible.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clock.tick()'s parameter is used to call the SDL sleep function to limit how many times the loop runs per second.

Calling it with Clock.tick(5) limits it to five loops per second.

I've also never used two clocks in the same code, especially with the multiple ticks (all of which will calculate their sleep time individually). Instead of that, consider using the return value of tick (the time in ms since the last call), and use that to track time through the whole application.

Example:

```
    timer = 0
    Do things
    timer += main_clock.tick(FPS)
```